# Access Linkedin API

Tags: r

According to LinkedIn Website, i have togenerate an access token, with a HTTP POST against accessToken with both my Client ID and Client Secret values.
I have to post against

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

With three different parameters: "grant_type" ( The value of this field should always be  `client_credentials`), "client_id" and "client_secret" both provided by linked in

At the moment, i did this:

```
require("httr")
require("jsonlite")
token<- POST("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", add_headers(
      grant_type ="client_credentials", 
      client_id = "keyprovided1", 
      client_secret = "keyprovided2"))
```

I have a 400 response, but it does not have the token.

There is something wrong?

Thank you!